# Ruby program to create even_odd method that accepts the whole number

Tags: ruby

I need help to write even_odd method that accepts an array of whole number.

1. It should return an array of 2 arrays
2. The first nested array should contain only the odd numbers
3. The second nested array should contain only the even numbers
4. If there are no even or odd numbers, the respective inner array should be empty

Output should look like this : -

```
even_odd([3, 5, 8, 2, 4, 6])
   [[3, 5], [2, 4, 6, 8]]

even_odd([3, 5])
   [[3, 5], []]

even_odd([2, 4])
   [[], [2, 4]]
```

I am new to ruby programming, I have tried below but not getting the result :-

```
def even_odd(numbers)
  arr1, arr2 = []
  idx = 0
  while idx < numbers.length
    if numbers[idx] % 2 == 0
    puts arr1[idx]   
    elsif 
    puts arr2[idx]
  end
  idx += 1
end
end
puts even_odd([2, 3, 6])
```

Error :-

```
main.rb:6:in `even_odd': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from main.rb:13:in `<main>'
```

Comment: "not getting the result" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: @avidCoder:  Why reinvent the wheel? `numbers.partition(&:odd?)` would do exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: @JörgWMittag - Sorry i forgot to add the error. Let me add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this

```
def even_odd(numbers)
  numbers.sort.partition(&:odd?)
end

even_odd([3, 5, 8, 2, 4, 6])
# => [[3, 5], [2, 4, 6, 8]]
even_odd([3, 5])
# => [[3, 5], []]
even_odd([2, 4])
# => [[], [2, 4]]
```

Comment: This worked.  Easiest way. Actually, I have not yet studied partition object. Anyway. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`puts` is a print statement in ruby, not an append one. It also doesn't run a function/method. You'll also want to call the index on the numbers array inside the if...else block.

This should do the trick:

```
def even_odd(numbers)
  arr1, arr2 = [], []
  idx = 0
  while idx < numbers.length
    if numbers[idx] % 2 == 0
      arr1 << numbers[idx]
    elsif 
      arr2 << numbers[idx]
    end
  idx += 1
  end
  return arr1, arr2
end

arrays = even_odd([2, 3, 6])
puts arrays
```

Comment: Or even simpler: `numbers.partition(&:odd?) # => [[3, 5], [8, 2, 4, 6]]`

Comment: But good job at fixing their code without completely rewriting it.